# How powerdns slaves track changes of master in mysql backend?

Tags: mysql, wan, replication

I'm using bind for many years i want to migrate to powerdns.

Assume the dns servers better to be locate on many data centers replication always to be problem.

How powerdns manage the zone transfer changes to slaves? MySQL need to be replicated over WAN via TLS ?
Or master powerdns will send the changes to slave automatically if changes applied. Or slaved check interval for changes?

I need to know about failover challenges on data replication and how power dns act on this situation?

Comment: Why offtopic, it's about operation software for system administrators? @davidpostill

Comment: Read the off -topic message

Comment: @davidpostil I confess that I also dont understand why you closed this as off topic. I dont think this is a software or learning recommendation. Please reconsider.

Comment: I dont know the answer.to your question, but on my systems I ush the visible DNS records on each powerdns instance from a master server.

Comment: @davidgo so we dont need mysql on slaves ? slaves check intervally for changes from master wiithout require the mysql access ?

Comment: I run a database instance on each DNS server and "replicate" (just sync the tables) to all of them from a "hidden master" which is actually my web interface.

Comment: @davidgo that's my point about mysql replicate fails, thats usual on WAN connection. Not's about TLS communication on replication that's my desire workflow. I think you have to share your solution, at least i could not find easily. modify my question if needed to be document

Comment: @davidgo even better to write medium article about it.